# Apache Beam initialize an PCollection to empty

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam

I trying to convert a Spark ETL application into a Beam Application.

Inside the Spark App, I have an empty RDD.

`sc.emptyRDD()`

where `sc` is the `SparkContext`.

If I well understand, the `PCollection` is like Spark `RDD`. So, there is a way to create an empty `PCollection`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Create.empty()`. Since `PCollection`s are typed and require coders, you'll also need to specify the coder or a type descriptor (even though the collection is empty), e.g. `PCollection<String> emptyStrings = Create.of(StringUtf8Coder.of())`.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

```java
PCollection<String> output = p.apply(Create.empty(StringUtf8Coder.of()));
```